# Computing normal vector of a face in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tasked with creating a function that calculates the face normal. To do this I must find the vertices returned from a previous function, `read_face_data`, which I did. I am now unsure of where to go from here. Attached is the prompt I was provided for this program, which explains in detail what I need to do.

I tried the following code:

```py
def compute_face_normal(fp, face_index):
    '''Insert docstring here.'''
    first, second, third = read_face_data(fp, face_index)
    read_vertex_data()
    compute_cross()
    return
```

Prompt:

> You should first find the vertices of the face from the mesh file
>   using the face_index and the read_face_data function. That function
>   returns 3 vertices. You can capture the three vertices returned from
>   the functoion like this: first, second, third = read_face_data(fp,
>   face_index) You will find the normal at the first vertex. For each
>   vertex you need their three coordinates; read_vertex_data can be used.
>   Note that to calculate the normal vector, you need to calculate the
>   coordinates of the sides first. The vector components (vector
>   coordinates) through two points (initial and terminal points) in
>   three-dimensional space is calculated as the difference between the
>   coordinates of each point. For example, if A and B are the initial and
>   terminal points with coordinates (x1,y1,z1) and
>   (x2,y2,z2)respectively, the coordinates of vector AB are:
>   (x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1) Find the vectors of the two sides and then take
>   their cross product using your compute_cross function.

Comment: Could you show some code that you've tried?

Comment: def compute_face_normal(fp, face_index):
    '''Insert docstring here.'''
    first, second, third = read_face_data(fp, face_index)
    read_vertex_data()
    compute_cross()
    return

Comment: okay, could you now explain why the code you tried doesn't work the way you want? What output do you expect? Please edit your post to add these informations.